# Import Media To CPT with CLI & Filter Custom Taxonomy

Tags: wp-cli

I have a lot of Custom Posts that I need to set featured images for, based on a custom taxonomy.
I am trying to see if there is a way to do this via wp-cli, I see an example offered there which would let me import and set an image to all posts of the CPT. However I cannot figure out if it is possible to further filter that by a custom taxonomy.

```
ATTACHMENT_ID="$(wp media import ~/Downloads/image.png --porcelain)"
wp post list --post_type=post --format=ids | xargs -0 -d ' ' -I % wp post meta add % _thumbnail_id $ATTACHMENT_ID
```

The command [wp post list](http://wp-cli.org/commands/post/list/) has an optional field for "filter", is that useful, I cannot see what it does.

Answer (score 2):

In WP-CLI list the arguments in `WP_Query` are defined by the associated arguments like `--post_type=post`. To be able to filter custom taxonomies you would need to use `tax_query`. Unfortunately WP-ClI does not support argument array so it is not possible.

It is on the other hand possible with the WP-CLI Rest package. You can install it by running `wp package install wp-cli/restful`.

You should be able to query it with the command `wp rest post list`

https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/issues/3039